# How to check sessions on every action of a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

i have a controller called `AllEntities` it has multiple actions like `GetEntityByTypeId` and `GetLastEntity`

i want to do a session check whenever `AllEntities` controller is used

like suppose i request a url `http://localhost:59656/AllEntities/GetLastEntity`
then it should check weather session is assigned or not

one way of doing this would be put condition `if (Session["userName"] == null)`
in every Action of this controller
How can it be checked once for entire `AllEntities` controller

any kind of help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could override the controllers `Initialize` method which would fire on every action. I use it to populate ViewBag elements I need on multiple/all views.

```
public class YourController : Controller
{

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);

        try
        {
            //do your session check here...

            //alternatively, if you wanted to limit to certain actions in your controller you could say: 
            var actionName = requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString().ToLower();
            if(actionName == "actionName" || actionName == "actionName2") {
               //do your limited session work...
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }

    }
    ...
```